# AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening

Tags: python, audio

**This is the code:**

```
import pyttsx3

import datetime

speech_recognition as sr  

engine = pyttsx3.init('sapi5')

voices = engine.getProperty('voices')

engine.setProperty('voice', voices[1].id)

def speak(audio):

engine.say(audio)

engine.runAndWait()

def wishMe():

hour = int(datetime.datetime.now().hour)

if hour >= 0 and hour < 12:

speak("Good Morning!")

elif hour >= 12 and hour < 18:

    speak("Good afternoon!")

else:

    speak("good Evening!")

speak("I am Jarvis... How may I help you")

def takeCommand():

r = sr.Recognizer()  
   
print("listening...")  

r.pause_threshold = 1

audio = r.listen(source)

try:

    print("Recognising...")

    query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
    
    print(f"user said:{query}\n")

except Exception as e:  

   

    print("Say that again pls")
   
    return "None"  

return query

if name == 'main':

wishMe()  

takeCommand()
```

**I am getting Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\shish\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\jarvis1.py", line 72, in
takeCommand()
listening...
File "C:\Users\shish\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\jarvis1.py", line 50, in takeCommand
audio = r.listen(source)
File "C:\Users\shish\python1\lib\site-packages\speech_recognition_init_.py", line 594, in listen
assert source.stream is not None, "Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for AudioSource; are you using source outside of a with statement?"
AssertionError: Audio source must be entered before listening, see documentation for AudioSource; are you using source outside of a with statement?

Process finished with exit code 1
```

**please help**

The program is expected to print what I speak

Comment: Hey there, I would like you to take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and go through [how do I ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and make the necessary changes. Its always a good practice to show your research so far related to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I reviewed your code and there was a problem in your takecommand() function. You forgot to mention what is your audio source. Your code should go like this...

```
def takecommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print("Listening....")
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
     print("Recognizing....")
     query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-in')
     print(f"user said: {query}\n")
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      return "None"
    return query
```